# Bootstrap 4.6 Tooltip not showing in dynamically generated modal content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm dynamically populating a Bootstrap 4.6 modal dialog and the element with a tooltip is no longer showing the tooltip.

```
<div class="modal-tooltip text-center mb-2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<strong>Theme 1</strong><br><span class='small'>This is a longer description of the Theme</span>">
  <span class="card-text m-1 px-3 py-2 rounded" style="background-color: grey; color: white;">
    <strong><a class="text-white" href="/themes/1">Theme 1</a></strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

On previous advice from this website I added a handler for the loading of the modal dialog to activate the tooltips on the element:

(this is in RoR - hence on 'turbo links:load' event)

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load',function() {

  // re-enable tooltips/popover on show modal
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960446/bootstrap-tooltip-doesnt-work-in-modal
  $('#my_lg_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {      
    console.log("modal shown");
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
  });

});
```

I know the code is running when showing the dialog because the "modal shown" message is showing in console.

I also tried adding this CSS but I'm sure that's not the issue as the "title" displays as an unformatted mouseover text but not as a tooltip-formatted element.

```
// fix for tooltips in modal dialog
.modal-tooltip {
  z-index: 100000000; 
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Make sure the tooltips are found with your selector, and if you run it manually in the console after the modal is shown does it work? Example `$('#my_lg_modal').find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()`

Comment: Good point - I didn't test this from the console. However yes, whether I use your code or my code, when I enter this code in at the console the tooltips will now correctly be displayed.

Comment: Okay this got me thinking and has answered the problem. The modal is shown when the user clicks on a link - but the modal content is dynamically generated, and so the relevant element is not yet present when the show.bs.modal event is triggered.

I moved the JS into the code responsible for populating the modal dialog content, and it now works!